# Label or index images

Tags: graphics, labeling, grid-layouts

Question:

How can I index (like in the example below: "c" and "d") images outside the frame?

[image]

I started to code, but I got stuck in the lack of documentation:

```
state0 = Import[
  "d:\\bitbucket\\monte-carlo-borderline\\pics\\torus-0-l5.png"]
state3 = Import[
  "d:\\bitbucket\\monte-carlo-borderline\\pics\\torus-3-l5.png"]
GraphicsGrid[{{state0, state3}}, Spacings -> {1, 2}, Frame -> All]
```

Input images:

[image][image]

Part-result:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question, so I can't help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
states = {state0, state1, ImageMultiply[state0, Red], ImageMultiply[state0, Yellow]};
labels = {"(a)", "(b)", "(c)", "(d)"};
```

**Labeled**

```
Grid[Partition[Labeled[Show[#, ImageMargins -> {{30, 0}, {0, 0}}], 
 Style[#2, 16], {{Top, Left}}] & @@@
  Transpose[{states, labels}], 2], Spacings -> 5]
```

[image]

**Legended**

```
Grid[Partition[Legended[Show[#, ImagePadding -> {{40, 0}, {0, 40}}], 
     Placed[Style[#2, 16], {{0, 1}, {1.1, 0}}]] & @@@ 
   Transpose[{states, labels}], 2], Spacings -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you extend it to a 2 x 2 grid solution (a,b,c,d)? 
Then I accept it. It is OK with the same pictures.

Comment: @pnz, please see the update.

Answer (score 0):

```
Grid[{{Labeled[state0, "state0", {{Top, Left}}], 
       Labeled[state3, "state3", {{Top, Left}}]}}]
```

**Edit:**

You can always use Framed to put a frame around each graph individually. E.g.,

```
Grid[{{Labeled[Framed[state0], "state0", {{Top, Left}}], 
       Labeled[Framed[state3], "state3", {{Top, Left}}]}}]
```

Comment: I try it, but it seems the labels are inside the frame:

GraphicsGrid[{{Labeled[state0, "a", {{Top, Left}}], 
   Labeled[state3, "b", {{Top, Left}}]}}, Spacings -> {1, 2}, 
 Frame -> All]

Comment: The labels are outside the graphics frame.  Naturally, they are inside the grid frame.  (How else could that work with e.g. a 2d grid?)  You can always use `Framed` to put a frame around each graph individually.  E.g., `Grid[{{Labeled[Framed[state0], "state0", {{Top, Left}}], 
   Labeled[Framed[state3], "state3", {{Top, Left}}]}}]`.