# Adding an identifying letter to plots in a standard position

Tags: plotting

It is customary in many publications to mark diagrams with a large identifying letter - an example is shown below. What functionality in Mathematica is useful for adding such identifiers, and how can the functionality be used so that the relative position of the identifier is the same across diagrams of similar dimensions, but not necessarily similar axes ranges?

[image]

Comment: `It is customary in many publications to mark diagrams with a large identifying letter`. I would not do this. I think a better way is to use a figure number. As in adding a caption in Latex. As this page shows https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions  .  But if you really need a letter thrown on the figure, you could use the `Text` command in mathematica. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html need to play with position a little to get the letter to show at right location.

Comment: closely related: [Label of index images](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/158318/125)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in comment, I think you are approaching this in wrong way. But if you really want to add additional letter somewhere on a plot, simply use the `Text` command. You might need to adjust the coordinates where the letter show and the style as you prefer. Using the `Scaled` option for the position means the relative position will be the same on the plot each time. This is better than using absolute coordinates.

```
Plot[ 1/(1 + (x + 3)^2), {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> False, PlotLabel -> Style[Row[{"My Diagram"}], Bold, 14] , 
 Epilog -> Text[Style["B", Red, 14], Scaled[{0.05, .95}]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I do not know of specialized command in Mathematica to do what you said

> What functionality in Mathematica is useful for adding such
>   identifiers, and how can the functionality be used so that the
>   relative position of the identifier is the same across diagrams of
>   similar dimensions

The better way to do this, is to use Mathematica to generate the plots. Save them to PDF files. Then import them to your Latex document using `includegraphics` and then use Latex `Caption` to add figure numbers and titles.

With Latex, you can now refer to figures from anywhere in the document, and even add page numbers where the figure is, all done automatically by Latex.